# using variables to populate multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Some background.  I am using an application called vRealize Orchestrator that has multiple workflows.  Each workflow will record three variables and I need to pass those variables into a table. Additional workflows can be added so I am keeping the logic somewhat open ended.  Here is my code.

```
if(inTable == null){
    outTable = new Array();
    outTable = ([testName],[testScore],[testNotes]);
}
else{
    outTable = new Array();
    outTable = inTable
    outTable.push([testName],[testScore],[testNotes]);
}
```

inTable would be the primary array holding all of the results from the modules. Regardless of which module is called first it will initialize and just push the variable values to the array.  If inTable already has data it should just append.

I can store data and when I output it looks like this "john, mary, steve" and is seen as a single string so I cant address it later.  How can I get these as individual elements so arry[0][0] will equal "john" rather then "j".

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `(a, b, c)` does not mean what you think it means

Comment: Why are you making `new Array`s and then replacing them?

Comment: Why are you wrapping single items in arrays?

Comment: What is `outTable = ([testName],[testScore],[testNotes]);` supposed to accomplish? You were probably looking for `outTable = [[testName],[testScore],[testNotes]];`

Comment: ([testName],[testScore],[testNotes]) are variables.  For example testName = "Check OS", testScore = 100 and testNotes = "OS check passed".

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you're looking for:

```
if(inTable == null){
    outTable = [[testName],[testScore],[testNotes]];
}
else{
    outTable = inTable;
    outTable[0].push(testName);
    outTable[1].push(testScore);
    outTable[2].push(testNotes);
}
```

This way, `outTable[0][0]` will give you `"John"`.

As a personal note, I don't know how much control you have over the data model or how exactly you plan/have to use it, but this doesn't look very optimal to me. Usually when we store table-like data, we use an array of objects:

```
var table = [
    { name: 'John', score: 50, notes: 'Good effort' },
    { name: 'Alice', score: 60, notes: 'Well argued' },
];
```

This way, `table[0].name` will give you `"John"`.

Comment: Correct but testName, testScore and testNotes are all variables.  Each module will produce these three variables and I need to add them into a master table which will then provide a report.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign outTable to inTable, you are assigning by value. This means that when you update outTable it does not update inTable accordingly. With the wording of your question it sounds like you would like to append values to inTable. This would be closer to what you are looking for if I am correct.

```
if( inTable == null )
{
    inTable = new Array();
}

inTable.push( [testName], [testScore], [testNotes] );
```

This way

```
inTable[ index ][0] == [testName]
inTable[ index ][1] == [testScore]
inTable[ index ][2] == [testNotes]
```

Comment: that is very close to what I am looking for [0][0] does provide me with the value of testName however [0][1] and [0][2]  result as undefined.